dynamic optimization with a differential constraint
In Benevolent Social Planner's Problem, there's a dynamic optimization problem with fixed horizon $T$, that is (simplified):
$$ \max_{c_t,k_{t+1}} \sum_0^{T} \beta^t u(c_t) \quad \text{s.t.} \quad c_t+k_{t+1}\leq f(k_t), $$
where $k_0$ is given.
I'm confused about how to solve this dynamic optimization problem with  differential constraints.
It may be solved through a recursive method or a total Lagrangean method. I wonder can I solve this problem using a tradition calculus method, or a control theory method with Hamiltonian function.
